# Prayer for miracles on Chanuka/Purim

Tags: halacha, miracle

The Rema Orach Chaim Siman 682 writes,

הגה י"א כששכח על הנסים בברכת המזון כשמגיע להרחמן יאמר הרחמן יעשה לנו נסים ונפלאות כשם שעשית לאבותינו בימים ההם בזמן הזה בימי מתתיהו כו' [כל בו]

Gloss: There are opinions that if one forget "For the miracles" in the grace after meals, when one reaches "the merciful one", say: "May the merciful one make miracles for us just like You make for our forefathers in those days at this time, in the days of Matityahu etc. (Sefaria translation)

Alot was written regarding this blessing of הרחמן, becaues it seems to contradict what the Gemara says in Berachos 60a that one may not pray for miracles (see here שערי תשובה או"ח סי' קפ"ז [https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.187.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.187.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Many ideas were discussed throughout the generations, but the common denominator is that at that point in time (either Chanukah or Purim) one does have an unique opportunity to pray for miracles...

Since this הרחמן is such a unique and special prayer (praying for miracles), then why does one merit to say it 'only' when he forgot to say the 'real thing' (על הניסים)?

Comment: The premise is incorrect. You can say it whenever you want on Purim,not just if you forget

Comment: the question is why isn't the primary prayer

Comment: The idea I'm about to say is not sourced anywhere (I think), but לפע"ד the reason rabanan did this was to tell a person that, "if you forgot to say al hanisim it means the miracles of Chanukah and Purim are not inscribed within you, it didn't excite you so much, had it been exciting for you, you would have waited for the opportunity to say it! Therefore rabanan tried to relate a bigger message that will maybe be engrained within him for the duration and Chanukah and Purim. Which is that not only can Hashem perform awesome miracles like these, but can also create miracles in the future.

Comment: For some people, this *is* included in the על הנסים. Look up כשם שעשית in Rambam's seder tefillah, for example.

Comment: Avishai, I like it!! Based on what your saying, I would say it differently (perhaps ע"ד צחות ). Hashem doesn't make miracles for someone that's 'wowed' by miracles, because that would remove his בחירה (or for other reasons mentioned in seforim), however this person that forgot על הניסים then apparently he's unimpressed, because he believes that Hashem can easily perform miracles equally the same as every natural phenomenon in the world. This person is allowed to pray for miracles because it's like every other prayer!!! Once again Avishai well done..

Comment: @shayachagigah, appreciate its so much, thanks! You worded it better than I did